# how to reset root password in phpmyadmin using xampp server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

HI Any one can help me that how i can reset my phpmyadmin root password.
when i am going to open localhost/phpmyadmin i got this error..

> "
>    Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'. "

and when i click on user to change my password i face this error

> Error : Token mismatch

I also try this method:
After started  XAMPP server, i go to the browser and type the URL localhost/security/ (incase you've modified XAMPP server port, you need to include that port number also in previous URL). The security page will be shown where you can change the root password for MySQL. This will update the phpMyAdmin config also.

i have follow this method but i cannot solve my problem plz help me out this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resetting MySQL Root Password with XAMPP on Localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566453/resetting-mysql-root-password-with-xampp-on-localhost)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php`

then

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'WhateverPassword';//near line 21
```

or Run this command

```
mysqladmin.exe -u root password 'WhateverPassword'
```

And **Possible Duplicate of** [Resetting MySQL Root Password with XAMPP on Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566453/resetting-mysql-root-password-with-xampp-on-localhost)

Comment: after doing this . when i am going to open localhost/phpmyadmin
i got "Access Denied "  this message

Comment: i load this command in run i have this directory
c > xamp > mysql > bin
now what i  to do in this directory??