# I am unable to login to phpmyadmin on window 8

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I install xampp server v3.2.1 and I change my user name and password in config.inc.php file.

**below my cofig.inc.php file.**

```
 <?php
/*
* This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
* cookie
*/
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
* Servers configuration
*/
$i = 0;

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'admin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] =false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/*/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma_savedsearches';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
*/

?>
```

When I am trying to login it show me following message:

[image]

I search a lot on internet but it did't work for me .please help me.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566453/resetting-mysql-root-password-with-xampp-on-localhost')

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Give your credentials in the following two lines, restart the xampp server and try login into phpmyadmin

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = <Your Username>;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = <Your Password>;
```

Comment: Mathun Kumar. I try it but not work for me give me the same error.

Comment: Try commenting/removing all " User for advanced features " and "Advanced phpMyAdmin features" statements..

Comment: I try it but not working for me. please give me other sold solution.