# set login enable for phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to enable the login page for phpmyadmin before entering into in directlt.
For that in my config.inc.php I modified the line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
to
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

After changed I caught access denied error as

[image]

I want to enable login for phpmyadmin

Comment: have you had restarted your xampp or wamp whatever you used ?

Comment: Change it back to true to see if it work again, you may have accidently change something else

Comment: After any change to config files you have to restart your server

Comment: Restart your server.

Comment: If I changed to true and checked.Its worked .redirect directly as before

Comment: restarted again still access denied for false

Comment: have you set password for it ?

Comment: no I want to redirect with blank password so left as it is

Comment: I changed password and restart my server still I caught access denied

Comment: try once with enable $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; rather than $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; and $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

Comment: It got redirect to login page but after logged with new password I shows  #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: now restart the server once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118000/discussion-between-user3386779-and-deep-kakkar).

Answer (score 7):

You can follow the steps shown below:

**Step 1:** Goto `phpMyAdmin` and find `Config.inc.php` file

**Step 2:** Find the line

```
$cfg ['Servers'] [$a] ['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

in `config.inc.php` file.

**Step 3:** 
Change the word `config` to `cookie` like so

```
$cfg ['Servers'][$a]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

in `config.inc.php` file and **Save** the changes.

Note:  your default database name is `root`.

**Step 4:** Now open browser and type `localhost/phpmyadmin`. Enter username is `root`. password is null means empty. you don’t type anything leave blank and press **GO** button.

**Step 5:** Now you can see the **change password** link. please click on that link.

Note: notice under `phpMyAdmin` title,  log out icon is visible.

**Step 6:** Set your phpMyAdmin password and retype again and press the GO button.