# Xampp MySQL refusing connection

Tags: mysql, xampp

Before you mark this a duplicate of a half-dozen or more questions related to this.

I have tried everything I've found online regarding this issue and I am still unable to resolve my problem.

Earlier today I change the password to root::localhost and immediately after doing so phpmyadmin started refusing access. I can gain temporary access (1 page at a time) by adding `skip-grant-tables` to `my.ini` and continually restarting MySQL every time I load a new page. I need to reset the password to blank. Is there a way with the latest version of xampp?

I found a way to reset my password to blank but every time I try to set one I get the same errors.

In the shell it recognizes my password and allows interaction through there but when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin or 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin it is throwing backtrace errors. Particularly `Use of undefined constant PMA_DRIZZLE - assumed 'PMA_DRIZZLE'`

```
Notice in .\libraries\Menu.class.php#565
 Use of undefined constant PMA_DRIZZLE - assumed 'PMA_DRIZZLE'

Backtrace

.\libraries\Menu.class.php#108: PMA_Menu->_getServerTabs()
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#85: PMA_Menu->_getMenu()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#308: PMA_Menu->getHash()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#395: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()

Notice in .\libraries\Menu.class.php#598
 Use of undefined constant PMA_DRIZZLE - assumed 'PMA_DRIZZLE'

Backtrace

.\libraries\Menu.class.php#108: PMA_Menu->_getServerTabs()
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#85: PMA_Menu->_getMenu()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#308: PMA_Menu->getHash()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#395: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
 PMA_Response::response()

Notice in .\libraries\Menu.class.php#565
 Use of undefined constant PMA_DRIZZLE - assumed 'PMA_DRIZZLE'

Backtrace

.\libraries\Menu.class.php#108: PMA_Menu->_getServerTabs()
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#73: PMA_Menu->_getMenu()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#319: PMA_Menu->getDisplay()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#395: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()

Notice in .\libraries\Menu.class.php#598
 Use of undefined constant PMA_DRIZZLE - assumed 'PMA_DRIZZLE'

Backtrace

.\libraries\Menu.class.php#108: PMA_Menu->_getServerTabs()
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#73: PMA_Menu->_getMenu()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#319: PMA_Menu->getDisplay()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#395: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()
```

are the four error messages I get if I don't attempt to reconnect after resetting the password

Comment: Do you remember the password you used?

Comment: Yes, I remember the password I used.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can verify that it is indeed running

Comment: Are you using Windows or a *nix

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using Windows, Windows 10 if that makes any difference

Comment: Then this should solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/24566453/2310830

Comment: the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` is non-existent in my config.inc.php, I've already tried that answer.

Comment: Does XAMPP throw a login dialog when you try and run phpMyAdmin

Comment: @RiggsFolly Error
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Try your question on http://askubuntu.com/. Users here mostly aren't following or skillful about server/db-administration

Comment: Stackoverflow is reserved for coding. There are dedicated forums for database administration https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and server admninistration https://serverfault.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

I'm running xampp on Windows 7 and had the exact same problem.
Here's how I solved it.

Like the asker, I first added `skip-grant-tables` to `mysql\bin\my.ini` file.
After restarting mysql, phpMyAdmin was able to list databases, but was still displaying a connection error when trying to reach them.

I looked at the `phpMyAdmin` folder and observed that the `config.inc.php` file had the date when the problem occured.

In my case, the problem occured just after attempting to install a new PHP/MySQL software, who had asked me an administrator password. The fact is that this password was applied to all my databases. Hence the problem.
I was lucky enough to remember that password and entered it in phpMyAdmin's configuration file, `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'theDamnedPasswordHere'`.
This solved the problem.

Then, I also entered the password in `my.ini`, so that I could remove the `skip-grant-tables` directive.

Comment: The damned software that caused the trouble was 'Elitius Affiliate Management Software'. Beware!