# .Net connection string to connect MySQL localhost Without Password

Tags: mysql, .net-core, phpmyadmin, xampp

What will be the connection string in appsettings.json file for **MySQL localhost without password for root**?
I tried below but not working!

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDbName;Uid=root;SslMode=none
```

On the opposite direction, I also set password for root user using user accounts in phpMyAdmin as describe here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34562915/11276273
But no luck.

Please suggest the solution.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1) what is the error message you have encountered; 2) is the mysql running fine; 3) is your firewall allow the connections or not

Comment: @BagusTesa,
1) Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
2) Yes it's perfectly running without password.
3) Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `localhost`, try using your local IP address in the connection string and Modify the Host name to **ANY HOST** for root user from phpmyadmin 
[image]